# Images from common project

Tags: c#, image

I have 4 projects in same solution. In one project the images get uploaded & stored in some folder.Now I want to show this image in another project which is in same solution.What code should I write in C#?

Comment: In what kind of environment to you operate? Web? Winforms? WPF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep the ImageFolder path in config file in all the project.

And that path can be use to Read/Write the image(s).

Comment: System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image imd = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image();
            imd.Width = 220;
            imd.Height = 215;
            string abc = Request.Url.AbsolutePath.ToString();
            imd.ImageUrl = "/project1/Images/homepg_banner.jpg";
            lblImage.Controls.Add(imd);

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me that it would be sensible that the same project responsible for *storing* the images should be responsible for *retrieving* them too... either by providing a filename "mapping" service (e.g. original upload filename mapped to physical location on disc) or by giving a method which will open the file and return a `Stream` to the data. Then showing the image becomes a matter of calling that method and then loading the image as normal.

It's hard to be more precise without more details of what you're trying to do, how the image is stored etc. What have you already tried, and what problems have you run into?

Comment: i am storing .jpg image and I have tried following code                 System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image imd = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image();
            imd.Width = 220;
            imd.Height = 215;
            string abc = Request.Url.AbsolutePath.ToString();
            imd.ImageUrl = "/project1/Images/homepg_banner.jpg";
            lblImage.Controls.Add(imd);                                                                                                                But this is working only on IIS but not on localhost. I want the code working on both. Help me.

Comment: @ykapase: And is the image there and visible? What happens with your current code? I notice that you're not actually using `abc` anywhere in your code... If it's working in IIS but not when testing, then presumably your test server doesn't server plain files, or doesn't have that URL mapped.